# How do we report a regression with categorical * continouns interaction?

Tags: r, linear-model, lm, reporting, centering

I was wondering how would be the best way to report [this model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588078/what-does-1-unit-change-mean-when-centering-predictors-in-regression?noredirect=1#comment1086770_588078) ?

```
### This model is from Winter (2019:139)
# Center SER: mutate(SER_c = SER - mean(SER, na.rm = T)
# Model:

lm(Iconicity ~ SER_c * POS)

term  estimate
intercept 0.66
SER_c     0.11
POSVerb   0.72
SER_c:POSVerb 0.50

Obs: SER_c is a centered continuos predictor and POS is a categorical predictor with 2 levels (Nouns and Verbs)
```

- **[1](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588078/what-does-1-unit-change-mean-when-centering-predictors-in-regression?noredirect=1#comment1086770_588078)** I know that I cannot talk about main effects because B1 and B2 are simple effects, so would it be sth like:

*"a regression model predicts an effect of SER (b = 0.11, p < 0.5) and POS (POS's beta is a composed beta between B1 + B3, so I dont know what I should report here?) as well as a significant interaction between the variables (b3 = 0.50, p < 0.05). Iconicity (the Y variable) is 0.66 for NOUNS w/ AVERAGE SER and 1.38 for VERBS w/ AVERAGE SER and the positive interaction indicates that Verbs are more iconic (the Y variable is iconicity) than Nouns for average SER words"*

- **[2](https://benjamins.com/catalog/is.18.3.07win)** Also, I can talk about the interaction effect as a moderator/control, cant I? Like this:

*"we have controlled for SER in our model"*

- [This is the paper](https://benjamins.com/catalog/is.18.3.07win) in which Winter (the book's author) reports these results, but authors didn't include the interaction in the final version, so I'm a bit confused on how to report that

It is my first time reporting a centered lm with a significant interaction between a centered continuos variable and a categorical variable with two levels, I wanna get it right. I'd really appreciate some advice on that! Thanks in advance!

[This post was helpful, but I couldn't make it to my example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/226559/how-should-i-report-the-results-from-a-mixed-model-with-vs-without-an-interactio)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centering (more generally, standardizing) predictors can make the regression coefficient harder to interpret. This seems to happen in your example because nouns and verbs have different mean SER.

I didn't know what SER is (and I still don't), so I was looking at (Winter 2017) to figure it out. In a great example of reproducibility, the data and the code for that analysis are available on [GitHub](https://github.com/bodowinter/iconicity_senses/).

This means I was able to reproduce your regression.

```
#>   (Intercept)          SER_c        POSVerb  SER_c:POSVerb  
#>        0.6642         0.1182         0.7237         0.5084
```

But first I wanted to look at the distribution of SER for nouns and verbs.

[image]

You can see from the histogram that verbs tend to have lower SER than nouns. We can also compute the average SER by part of speech (POS).

```r
#> # A tibble: 2 × 3
#>   POS       n `mean(SER)`
#>   <chr> <int>       <dbl>
#> 1 Noun   1106        3.42
#> 2 Verb    373        2.96
```

So, while SER = 0 might be arbitrary, so may be the average SER of verbs and nouns (in this dataset). The (unweighted) sample mean SER is a 3:1 combination of the mean noun SER (3.42) and the mean verb SER (2.96):

```r
(1106 * 3.42 + 373 * 2.96) / (1106 + 373) = 3.3
```

This average is hard to interpret. It follows that the concepts of "NOUNS w/ AVERAGE SER" and "VERBS w/ AVERAGE SER" are also hard to interpret.

Instead I would report the model as two regression lines, one for nouns and one for verbs. Here is the model overlaid on top of the data.

[image]

*Appendix*

Since POS is categorical, the model `Iconicity ~ SER * POS` is equivalent to a separate regression line for each category. (The errors about the regression lines have the same variance.) The interaction term is a specific parametrization which indicates that the regression slope is different for nouns and verbs.

$$
\begin{aligned}
Y 
&= \beta_0 + \beta_1\text{SER}
+ \beta_2\operatorname{Is}\left\{\text{Verb}\right\}
+ \beta_3\text{SER} \times \operatorname{Is}\left\{\text{Verb}\right\}
\\
&= 
\operatorname{Is}\left\{\text{Noun}\right\}
\color{red}{\Big[\beta_0 + \beta_1\text{SER}\Big]}
+ \operatorname{Is}\left\{\text{Verb}\right\}
\color{blue}{\Big[(\beta_0+\beta_2) + (\beta_1+\beta_3)\text{SER}\Big]} \\
&=
\operatorname{Is}\left\{\text{Noun}\right\}
\color{red}{\Big[\beta_0 + \beta_1\text{SER}\Big]}
+ \operatorname{Is}\left\{\text{Verb}\right\}
\color{blue}{\Big[(\tilde{\beta}_2 + \tilde{\beta}_3\text{SER}\Big]} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

B. Winter, M. Perlman, L. K. Perry, and G. Lupyan. Which words are most iconic?: Iconicity in english sensory words. *Interaction Studies*, 18(3):443–464, 2017.

Comment: thank you very much (once more!). Would you help me on reporting it in a paragraph? I mean, this is the way I usually see in my field, so I'd have to do that (as I tried to do in the post). My difficulty was on how to report the slope for POS, since it is a combination of B1 and B3 and on how to report the interaction @dipetkov

Comment: Why don't you report the two slopes, one for nouns and one for verbs? The intercepts are less meaningful (if SER = 0 is arbitrary).

Comment: but if the slopes depend on the interaction, then how do I account for that. Let me give you an example, I usually see it like this (without an interaction) "continuous predictor X increases Y by 0.11 (b = 0.11, p < 0.05) when the category is category A and by nvalue when Y is category B (b = nvalue, p < 0.05)" But since X2 slope is B1 + B3, I don't know how to report that in a similar way?

Comment: Is it really interesting to report that the slope for verbs, which is 0.627, is statistically different from 0?

Comment: thank you very much! I'm using this book as a guideline to the mod I'm modeling myself on real data (which also has an categorical*continuos) int). So what I'd like to be able to report is the effect size of each predictor, but I've never reported an interaction like this before, that's why I'm a bit confused. Concerning the p value, I guess that's just a convention to report it. Unfortunately, in my field, there's still a lack of people using lm and lmers, so I don't have so many ex, this is the way I've seen some good materials report in my field, so I'm trying to follow that

Comment: The interaction is the difference between the two slopes. In this particular example, one doesn't really need a p-value to see the slopes are different. It can be often more intuitive to look at *contrasts* rather than regression *coefficients*. The coefficients depend on the parameterization: the same model can have many equivalent parametrizations. So I think it's harder to interpret the coefficients.

Comment: Here is how to use the [contrast](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/contrast/index.html) library to express the slope for verbs as a contrast (and to get its confidence interval and p-value): `contrast::contrast(fit, list(SER = 1, POS = "Verb"), list(SER = 0, POS = "Verb"))`. Spoiler alert: the p-value is numerically 0.

Comment: thank you very much (once more!!)! This is indeed the model that I've been trying to fit (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588224/lmer-violating-residuals-normality-assumption-what-should-i-do-when-enough-d) with this interaction and that I'm willing to report as soon as I come around the normality assumption